# Popup login form submission and validation using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, templates

I have popup div which asks for a username and password, and when user submits the form I have used ajax call to the php file to do the validation with the database. Now the problem is, I am not able to retain the same popup and the same page after the ajax call. The message is showing in a new page. Can anyone help me out with this?

My ajax call is like this:
Here I am doing a ajax call to `index.php` to retrieve whether echo/print string is displayed on the same popup. Usually in all other files if its not a popup I am able to get the message but finding it difficult in this case:

```
 function chk_login()
     {
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"index.php",
            data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
            success: function(js){
//js is returning a html object I should get that error message instead
                if(js!=1){
                    bootbox.alert(js)   
                    return false;
                }

            },
                error: function(){
                alert("Please try again. Server have not sent response.");
            }
        });
        return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display message on the **same pop-up** make a divison inside that pop-up and give it an id.
For Example:`<div id="displayMessage"></div>`
***You must have to create this divison inside your pop-up division.***
Now we can print server-response inside pop-up by using id of above division i.e.'displayMessage'.

Now your **ajax call** would look-like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"index.php",
        data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
        success: function(js){
            $("#displayMessage").html(js);/* 'displayMessage' is ID of div which lies inside pop-up & 'js' is our server-side responce */
        },
            error: function(){
            alert("Please try again. Server have not sent response.");
        }
    });
```